# Can Entity Framework classes have non-Entity Framework members?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have certain properties I want in the database but could I also have functions, and members that I don't want in the database in the same class? Is that a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are not stored in database. You can exclude members from database mapping (property or class will not be stored in database). You can do that with [NotMapped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[NotMapped]
public string Bar { get; set; }
```

or with [Ignore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671225%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) in fluent mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().Ignore(f => f.Bar);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: I knew functions weren't stored in the database but I thought the Entity Framework still might not like them. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @user1379635 yes, you can add any methods to your class, EF will map only data

Comment: Also by the way, is it possible to include stuff in the setter? Say I want to auto populate other fields when Entity Framework sets my value?

Comment: @user1379635 sure you can. EF simply calls setters, and inner logic is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the cleanest design, but there is no reason not to add methods to your entities...